# Split one string and put it in two arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, string, split

I'd like to split several strings of a text file into two strings each (example: car;driver). I do not know how to put the first word in array1 and the second word in array2. So I tried with an if query for a semicolon to put every single letter of word1 in array1 and the same with the second word to put them back together to the words later.

But I think it's too complicated what I've done and I am stuck now, lol.

Here I show a piece of my code:

```
private void BtnShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LibPasswords.Items.Clear();

            string path = "passwords.txt";

            int counter = 0;

            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fs))
            {
                while (reader.ReadLine() != null)
                {
                    counter++;

                }

                //for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
                //{
                //    var Website = reader.ReadLine().Split(';').Select(x => new String[] { x });
                //    var Passwort = reader.ReadLine().Split(';').Select(y => new String[] { y });
                //    LibPasswords.Items.Add(String.Format(table, Website, Passwort));
                //}

                string[] firstWord = new string[counter];
                string[] lastWord = new string[counter];

                int i = 0;
                int index = 0;
                while (reader.Peek() >= 0)
                {
                    string ch = reader.Read().ToString();
                    if (ch != ";")
                    {
                        firstWord[i] = ch;
                        i++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        index = 1;
                    }
                    while (reader.Peek() >= 0)
                    {
??????????????????????????????????
                    }
                }


            }
        }
```

Sorry for my English, it's not my mother tongue.

Answer (score 4):

As you don't know in advance how many lines there are, it is more convenient to use a `List<string>` instead of a `string[]`. A List will automatically increase its capacity as needed.

You can use the [string.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netcore-3.1) method to split the string at the ';' into an array. If the resulting array has the correct number of parts, you can add those parts to the Lists.

```
List<string> firstWord = new List<string>();
List<string> lastWord = new List<string>();

string fileName = @"C:\temp\SO61715409.txt";
foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(fileName))
{
    string[] parts = line.Split(new char[] { ';' });
    if (parts.Length == 2)
    {
        firstWord.Add(parts[0]);
        lastWord.Add(parts[1]);
    }
}
```